# memory returned from malloc function is not saving the data

Tags: c

In the below code I am not getting why the  `win[]` is not getting the values. I have commented on the line in the code below where I am confused.
   Pls help me guys.
   Am I doing any conceptual mistake.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void winner(int *speed,int *distance,int rats){
    float winner=(float)distance[0]/speed[0];
    float time;
    float *win=malloc(rats * sizeof(float));
    memset(win,0,rats*sizeof(float));
    for(int i=0;i<rats;i++) {
        time=(float)distance[i]/speed[i];
        if(time<=winner) {
            win[i]=time;   /*Problem is here*/ 
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<rats;i++) {
        if(win[i]!=0) {
            printf("%d\n",i+1);
        }
    }
    free(win);
}

int main() {
    int rats;
    int *speed,*distance;
    scanf("%d",&rats);
    speed=malloc(rats * sizeof(int));
    distance=malloc(rats * sizeof(int));
    for(int i=0;i<rats;i++) {
        scanf("%d",&speed[i]);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<rats;i++) {
        scanf("%d",&distance[i]);
    }
    winner(speed,distance,rats);
    free(speed);
    free(distance);
    return 0;
```

}

Comment: `memset(win,0,rats);` ---> `memset(win,0,rats * sizeof(float));`

Comment: Can you please provide some example input that causes the behavior? Have you tried stepping through the code line by line to see that it behaves as you expect?

Comment: How do you know the line with the comment "problem is here" is even executed?

Comment: How do you know it is not working? Are you sure `(time<=winner)` is true for some values?

Comment: I don't think that you can portably assume that "all bits zero" (what `memset()` would have given you if your third argument was right) means "floating point value equal to `0.f`". Use a loop.

Comment: this is the input.3(for rats)
70 35 45(for speed)
14 7 9(for distance)

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you should put some spaces into your program to make it more readable, e.g. `distance=malloc(rats*sizeof(int));` -> `distance = malloc(rats * sizeof(int));`

Comment: the line which i have pointed out is not saving the value of time in win[i].i have checked by using printf()  inside the if statement.

Comment: There is an obvious bug in your algorithm; apparently, you want to output the indexes of the winning rats, but instead, your program outputs the indexes of all rats which are faster than or equally fast to the first rat.

Comment: @MichaelWalz *could. It's an opinion, some people find it more readable when it has no spaces.

Comment: @ammoQ actually ptogram need to print the fastest rats ,if more than one rat has got the same time it needs to print all of them.

Comment: I guessed so, but your solution is not very close to the solution. Since this seems to be a homework assignment, I will not post the correct code to do that but rather describe it here: you don't need `win`; instead, update `winner` in the first loop whenever you find a faster rat. In the second loop, output all rats which are as fast as `winner`.

Comment: @ammoQ,,:D :D it's not a homework problem,,i was solving on hackerrank portal,i have solved the question but by other means,,,,but was not getting why this way it is not working....thanks for your advice :)

Comment: ok maybe the program is wrong,but if you try printf() to get the value of win[i] inside the if statement,you will find the win[i] is not getting assigned the value of time..

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 3 problems in your code :

- you do not change `winner` if one rat's time if shorter than first one
- you do not initialize `win[i]` for not winners
- you do no use the best time to display winning rats

So instead of :

```
    if(time<=winner){
       win[i]=time;   /*Problem is here*/
     }
```

you should have :

```
    win[i]=time; // always initialize !
    if(time<=winner){
       winner = time; // keep best time
    }
```

and then instead of

```
for(int i=0;i<rats;i++){
  if(win[i]!=0){
      printf("%d\n",i+1);
     }
 }
```

you should have :

```
for(int i=0;i<rats;i++){
  if(win[i] == time){ // display all rats having best time
      printf("%d\n",i+1);
     }
 }
```